# Laravel: Updating a single column in a single row?

Tags: laravel

For school we have to make a renting system for boats using laravel.
I am new to laravel and pretty new to programming in general.
In my YachtsController I have a function update that is called after editting all the values of a yacht in my edit.blade.php file. Now what I want to do is that if I click on a 'rent' button, that it will updated the yachts' status in the database from 'Available' to 'Unavailable'. How do I do this? Do I have to create a new function for this called 'rent'?

Yachts view:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['YachtsController@update', $yacht->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
   {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
   {{Form::submit('Rent',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

YachtsController:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'yachttype-list' => 'required',
            'port-list' => 'required', 
            'status' => 'required',
            'code' => 'required'
        ]);

        $yacht = Yacht::find($id);
        $yacht->name = $request->input('name');
        $yacht->yacht_type_id = $request->input('yachttype-list');
        $yacht->port_id = $request->input('port-list');
        $yacht->status = $request->input('status');
        $yacht->code = $request->input('code');
        $yacht->save();

        return redirect('/yachts')->with('success', 'Yacht updated!');
    }
```

So how do I make it that if I submit the form that the status will be changed?

EDIT:

So I tried now to make a new function called rent:

Yachts view:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['YachtsController@rent', $yacht->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
{{Form::submit('Rent',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

YachtsController rent function

```
    public function rent($id)
    {
        $yacht = Yacht::find($id);
        $yacht->status = "Unavailable";
        $yacht->save();
        return redirect('/yachts')->with('success', 'Yacht rented!');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('yachts/rent', 'YachtsController@rent');
Route::resource('yachts', 'YachtsController');
```

Now when I click on the Rent button on my view, it seems like it still validates the form in my update function and it gives me this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffo1.png)

Comment: yes, listen to the click event of "rent" button and create a new route and function to only update status

Comment: I have tried to create a new function called 'rent', I have edited my post can you check it out please

Comment: Do you have another form for that or what? just make the update form submit button "Update" and have "Rent" as a different button or form

Comment: Yes I made a new form with action to YachtsController@rent and submit button rent, but it still validates all elements of the old form for some reason

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Please don't "Edit" or "Update" tags in the question. Instead incorporate additional information into the question as if it was there initially; We can see what has changed because SO has revision tracking. Also, please don't link to resources that are off-site for information that is pertinent to the question. Links rot then break, and when they do the question becomes worthless to others searching for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your yachts/rent method is get, but in your view you use put method.
so when your form is submitted, it still go to yacth/{id} with put method (function update).and in your update function, there are validators so it give validation error.

my solution is create new put link and now function without validator in it..

in your route :

```
    Route::put('yachts/update_rent/{id}', 'YachtsController@update_rent')
```

in your controller :

```
    public function update_rent($id)
    {
        $yacht = Yacht::find($id);
        $yacht->status = "Unavailable";
        $yacht->save();
        return redirect('/yachts')->with('success', 'Yacht rented!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the validation errors from the `update` method is that Laravel thinks you're trying to update a whole yacht by PUTing to the route `/yachts/{yacht id}`. What you're actually wanting is to update a specific yacht in a specific way (rent it).

The best (my opinion) way to go about this is to modify your routes to explicitly create your PUT route with a name that you can then use on the form:

```
Route::put('yachts/{id}/rent', 'YachtsController@rent')->name('yacht.rent');
Route::resource('yachts', 'YachtsController');
```

And then your form can use the new named route:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['yacht.rent', $yacht->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Which should PUT your form to the correct route.

Comment: also `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` inside of the form

Comment: or pass `'method' => 'PUT'` to `Form::open` and it will add the `_method` spoof field